# Circle containing a point of square and touching two sides

Tags: geometry

So the problem goes,circle contains one vertex of a square and touches two sides. Length of side is 1cm. What is circumference of a circle?
My attempt was trying to find a connection between radius of circle, and side of square, but I'm not sure if Imagined and drew it properly.

Comment: You have not provided enough information for a comprehensible question. Contains one point? Does that mean it's on the circle or inside it? Which point?

Comment: My apologies, I meant it contains one vertex of a square.

Comment: Outer edge of circle points. What's the name for it?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the situation:

[image]

The radius from$(r,r)$ to $(1,1)$ is the hypotenuse of a right triangle of sides $1-r$ and $1-r$. Express this as an equation, which you can solve for $r$. (The equation will have two solutions; just pick the one with $r<1$.)

As a short cut, you can just look at that right-angled triangle and note that the ratio of the hypotenuse to the shorter sides is $\sqrt 2$.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Extend $AB$ one unit to the right to get point $E$,
$AD$ unit upwards to get point $F$
and connect these points.

Triangle $AEF$ is a right triangle 
with the sides $a=b=2$, $c=2\sqrt2$.
The circle is 
the inscribed circle for this triangle.

Recall that for any right triangle with sides $a,b$
and hypotenuse $c$, the radius
of the inscribed circle is just

\begin{align}
r&=\tfrac12(a+b-c)
,\\
\text{so }\quad
r&=2-\sqrt2
.
\end{align}